# How to increase Cache Size in Berkeley DB Java Edition

Tags: berkeley-db-je

I am using berkeley db java edition.
how can i increase cache size

Answer (score 1):

See EnvironmentConfig in the Javadoc, specifically, [setCacheSize](http://bit.ly/pI2KgZ).

Apologies for the delay in responding. Usually you can get these questions answered more quickly by posting them to the Berkeley DB Java Edition technical [forum](http://bit.ly/e1AYFi) on OTN.

Regards,

Dave